# Google V2 ReCaptcha not working for some users

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

We have implemented the V2 google invisible recaptcha for a contact us form. Every time I use it the recaptcha appears asking me to select some pictures which is great. But for some users the recaptcha is not appearing. Even though we are all in the same work place using the same site with the same form.

We have implemented both client and server side validation.

How is it possible that users within the same work place are getting different results with the recaptcha?

Comment: I want to say the browser is another factor to add in.

Comment: Good point Carlitos. I have already taken this into account though. Results are still sporadic across multiple browsers. Not only that spam is still getting through. I have since taken some custom approaches to this which is the honey pot solution and also building part of the form in JS to make sure JS is enabled on the page. The custom solutions have worked MUCH BETTER than Googles Recaptcha. In my eyes recaptcha is no longer safe to use and its days are over

Comment: Ill tell you one thing for sure is that the invisible captcha is better than the checkbox when it comes to determining spam

Comment: Have you got a source for that? V2 recaptcha whether visible or not should use the same algorithm to work out whether you are human or not

Comment: Just by experience I noticed some things. I installed over a hundred recatpchas at my job. Recently I installed the invisible captcha and that one seems to have less spam come through.